# jQuery Event Bubbling on wrong object

Tags: javascript, jquery, updatepanel, jquery-events

I'm still a little new to jQuery events.

I'm trying to write jQuery a wrapper/framework of the Asp.NET UpdatePanel that automatically tracks UpdatePanel async updates.

I want to be able to do something like

```
$("#myUpdatePanel").on("update", myFunc);
```

and have it run some handler with `this` as the updated UpdatePanel.  I actually have this bit working.

I also want to be able run a function exactly once any time one or many UpdatePanels update.

```
$.updatePanel.on("update", myRunOnceFunc);
```

This is where I'm having issues.

I've defined my wrapper:

```
// wrap updatePanel reload functionality
$.updatePanel = (function () {
    var prm;

    var UpdatePanel = function () { };
    UpdatePanel.prototype = { };

    // initialize on $(document).ready()
    $(function () {
        prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        if (prm) {
            prm.add_pageLoaded(function (s, e) {
                $.each(e.get_panelsUpdated(), function () {
                    // call panel-specific update event handlers
                    $(this).trigger($.Event("update"));
                });

                // triggered once no matter how many panels were updated
                $(UpdatePanel).trigger($.Event("update"));
            });
        }
    });

    return $(UpdatePanel);
})();
```

Then in my code that uses `$.updatePanel`:

```
$(function() { $.updatePanel.on("update", myRunOnceFunc); });
```

What I'm finding is that `myRunOnceFunc` is being run during both `$(this).trigger($.Event("update"));` and `$(UpdatePanel).trigger($.Event("update"));`.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.

Rather than `return $(UpdatePanel);`, I needed to call `return $(new UpdatePanel());`.  Then I needed to replace `$(UpdatePanel).trigger(...)` with `$.updatePanel.trigger(...)`.  Code below:

```
// wrap updatePanel reload functionality
$.updatePanel = (function () {
    var prm;

    var UpdatePanel = function () { }
    UpdatePanel.prototype = { };

    $(function () {
        prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        if (prm) {
            prm.add_pageLoaded(function (s, e) {
                $.each(e.get_panelsUpdated(), function () {
                    $(this).trigger($.Event("update"));
                });

                // triggered once no matter how many panels were updated
                $.updatePanel.trigger($.Event("update"));
            });
        }
    });

    return $(new UpdatePanel());
})();
```